# I want to move between images with the next and previous button in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I have a total of 4 images that I want to move between, but when I run the emulator it closes as soon as I press the Next or Previous button. When I press the Next button, the second image comes... and so on, and when I press the Previous button, the image before appears. This is the code.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView img;
    int[] photos = {R.drawable.car1, R.drawable.car2, R.drawable.car3, R.drawable.car4,};
    int i = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    }
    public void next(View view) {
        if ( i < 3 ) {
            i++;
        img.setImageResource(photos[i]);
        }
    }

    public void rev(View view) {
        img.setImageResource(photos[i]);
        if ( i > 0 ) {
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageView"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="300dp"/>

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_rev"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Previous"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:onClick="rev"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:onClick="next"/>
  </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

I want a solution to this problem and how can I move between the 4 images